# Angular value not being set in controller, but can be set in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm able to set the value of the query object within the view:

```
<button ng-click="query.Active = 'true'" ....
```

This updates the value bound to the filter and changes the view accordingly. Yet if I move that to the controller to be set:

```
<button ng-click="filterActive('true')"....
$scope.filterActive = function (type) { 
    $scope.query.Active = type;    
    console.log('active' + $scope.query.Active);
};
```

The result always returns undefined. I'm at a loss why the value is not being set.

Comment: Your code makes sense. Make sure you define the the button directive in the controller scope.

Comment: In your controller, did you define `$scope.query = {};` before trying to modify that object in `filterActive()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <button ng-click="query.Active=true"></button>
</div>
```

OR

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="active()"></button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.active = function() {
       $scope.query.Active = true;  
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is not being reflected in the view unless the value is set within the ng-click. Once moved the the controller it is no longer set.

Comment: Have you define `ng-app=""` on your parent container ?

Comment: Yes I have an ng-app. I was able to get it to work by passing: var filter = {
            Active: type
        };

        $scope.query = filter; into $scope.query.

Comment: no errors just undefined if I console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.query.Active));